# My method takes a List but Mockito.verify(writer.write(anyList())) gives a compile error

Tags: java, junit

I have a `FooWriter extends JDBCBatchItemWriter`

It has a method

```
public void write(final List<? extends Foo> fooList) throws 
Exception {
  super.write(fooList);
}
```

I am trying to write the JUnit tests for FooWriter.
I do not want the writer to actually write to the db so I am mocking it and just doing the verify.
However I get a compile error. I do not know what to put in the verify()
What should I put there?

```
class FooWriterTest {

  @InjectMocks
  FooWriter fooWriter;

  List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    // COMPILE ERROR!!
    Mockito.verify(fooWriter.write(anyList(List<Foo>)));
  }

  @Test
  void testWrite() {
    fooWriter.write(fooList);
}
```

Comment: Close the parentheses before the `.write` , so `verify(fooWriter).write(…..`

Comment: @racraman I edited my question to add the detail of `super.write()`. I changed the test method to be `verify(fooWriter).write(anyList())` but then I get a test failed error. "Argument passed to verify() is of type fooWriter and is not a mock". Should I just Mock fooWriter in the test class above?

Comment: The purpose of `verify` is to check that a particular method of a mock got called during the test.  It doesn't make any sense to use `verify` in the `setup` method.  It also doesn't make sense to use `verify` on any object other than a mock.  In this particular case, you seem to be verifying a call that you _know_ in the test that you've made, so I think it's probably safe just to remove it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I tried using a spy and a mockedStatic. Is it correct? (see my answer)

Comment: I don't think so, but it's hard to say, without seeing the code you're trying to test.  It really looks like you're calling a method, then checking whether you called that method.  I'm not sure that you're actually testing anything that's outside the test itself.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to be

```
FooWriter fooWriter = spy(FooWriter.class);

@Test
void testWrite() {
  try {MockedStatic<JdbcBatchItemWriter> mockedWriter = mockStatic(JdbcBatchItemWriter.class)) {
  fooWriter.write(fooList);
  mockedWriter.verify(()->fooWriter.write(anyList()));
 }
}
```

and it worked.